# Deploy dockerized spring boot web on App Engine

Tags: spring-boot, docker, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a Spring Boot web application which is currently deployed Google App Engine. Now I am shifted to Docker and want to deploy the docker image of this application on to App Engine.

So far, I could not find any document related to this. Most of the documents explain how to deploy a docker image of Spring boot on Tomcat. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need [App Engine using the flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments) , if you want deploy by docker image.

Here is the document [Building Custom Runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build).

> > A custom runtime allows you to use an alternate implementation of any supported App Engine flexible environment language, or to customize a Google-provided one. It also allows you to write code in any other language that can handle incoming HTTP requests (example). With a custom runtime, the App Engine flexible environment provides and manages your scaling, monitoring, and load balancing infrastructure for you, so you can focus on building your application.

In official case they have their sample DockeFile by jetty. But you can ignore the jetty part, just make your spring boot application  executable ,and run it.

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/jetty
ADD test-webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war $JETTY_BASE/webapps/root.war
WORKDIR $JETTY_BASE
RUN java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar --approve-all-licenses --add-to-startd=jmx,stats,hawtio 

 && chown -R jetty:jetty $JETTY_BASE
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the info!